# Derby built in functions

Tags: sql, derby, exponent

How do I calculate equivalent POWER(base, exponent) function in Apache Derby using SELECT statement?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Derby does not ship with a built-in `power(a, b)` function to compute `a^b`. However, you can easily compute it by simple high school math, if you remember your teenage years. I'm sure you do ;)

By math you know that:

```
a^b = e^(b * ln(a))
```

And it happens that Derby actually includes "natural logarithm" and "natural exponent". Therefore, your formula is (in Derby lingo):

```
power(a, b) = exp(b * ln(a))
```

To compute this expression in Derby you can use it any `SELECT`, or even simpler, just by using `VALUES`. For example `9^3.5` is:

```
values exp(3.5 * ln(9));
```

Result:

```
2187
```